# Problemas con los formatos de código

Tags: discusión

No ando con códigos ni nada, pero de las veces que ponía un codigo de **[c](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)**, siempre me decía:

*"Tu publicación parece contener código que no tiene el formato apropiado para código. Aplica una sangría de cuatro espacios a todo el código mediante el botón de código de la barra de herramientas o el método abreviado del teclado CTRL+K"*.

¿Cómo hago con eso?

Comment: Hola Roberto, tu pregunta es muy simpática, ya que en ella está su respuesta: escribe tu código, seleccionalo y dale ctrl+K, tambien tienes la opción de usar el botón **{}** que tiene la barra de herramientas.

Comment: Puedes ver [¿Cómo pegar código correctamente en Stack Overflow?](https://gist.github.com/abul4fia/b9a02ac828091125bf8062dd0203a55d).

Comment: Creí que estabas en huelga gbianchi.

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR

Personalmente, he visto a muchos usuarios que añaden código a sus preguntas, pero de manera errada, **lo que incentiva a dar un voto de cierre o a editar la pregunta**, pues la pregunta (visualmente), no cumple con los lineamientos de la comunidad y será difícil de entender.

**El editor de SO usa [MarkDown](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)**, por lo que es importante entender las normas de este lenguaje de marcado.

Teóricamente, se establece que, **en MarkDown, se puede introducir código de las siguientes maneras:**

- **Sangría de 4 espacios:** El procesador de MarkDown, admite introducir código con una sangría de 4 espacios.

  Ejemplo: En este ejemplo se dará una sangría de 4 espacios para que el intérprete de MarkDown lo procese como código.

  ```
  el código debería ir aquí.
  ```

  Desde el editor se ve así:

  [image: Cómo introducir código en StackOverflow]

  **Limitaciones**

  Aplicar una sangría de 4 espacios puede dificultar la comprensión rápida del *MarkDown* y el código introducido, en mi caso personal, lo hace. No se puede especificar el lenguaje de programación con el que se trabaja.
- **Usar triples comillas invertirdas (```):** Otra forma más legible y práctica es usar las triples comillas invertidas parra introducir código. Personalmente, considero que esta opción es más legible, debido a que se puede especificar en qué lenguaje de programación se trabaja.

  Ejemplo:

  ```js
  console.log("Hola");
  ```

  Desde el editor se ve así:

  [image: Cómo introducir código en StackOverflow]
- **Usar el servicio de StackSnippets:** También es eficiente usar los *StackSnippets* para introducir código en tu respuesta, esta función está integrada en el editor de respuestas. Lo puedes encontrar en la parte superior del editor con este símbolo: [image: StackSnippets].

  Lo único que tendrás que hacer es pulsarlo, y de pronto se abrirá una ventana como esta

  [image: Cómo introducir código en StackOverflow]

  Aquí, podrás introducir el código que necesites para tu respuesta, la ventaja es que se podrá reproducir y se podrá apreciar la funcionalidad de tu código. **Advertencia: Esta NO es una funcionalidad de *MarkDown*, sino nativa de StackOverflow**. **Limitaciones: Solo se puede introducir código [html](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [css](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) y [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).** Ejemplo:

```js
console.log("Hola mundo");
```

---

### Enlaces de interés y referencias

- [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
- [Sintaxis Markdown](https://markdown.es/sintaxis-markdown/)